# stop sharing printer win 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-shares

I have a laser printer in a lan with other computers and I want to be the only one able to print with this printer.
I want to stop the print share function of Windows, but I do NOT want to stop the file and print share service.
My roommates waste a lot of my toner and I want to be able to control what is being printed (they will hand me the pdf and I will print).
How do I stop the other computers from detecting my printer and start printing?

EDIT:

The printer is connected with USB to my computer

Comment: If you want to be the only want with access to the printer then disconnect it from the network.

Comment: Is this printer connected to your computer and shared via Windows? Or is it a network printer connected via Ethernet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the printer is connected to your PC and shared from there, then just stop sharing the printer.

Start -> Devices and Printers -> Right-click the printer -> "Printer Properties" -> Share tab -> Un-check "Share this printer".